# Can I use JUnit5 ClassOrderer to shuffle JUnit4 tests run via junit-vintage engine?

Tags: junit5, junit-vintage

If I use JUnit5 to run legacy JUnit4 tests, is there any way to configure it to use `ClassOrderer` for those JUnit4 classes? I saw in debugger that in `org.junit.jupiter.engine.discovery.AbstractOrderingVisitor#orderChildrenTestDescriptors` only JUnit5 tests are returned and processed.

I run tests from gradle, using quite simple config

build.gradle:

```
testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.8.1'
testRuntimeOnly 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.8.1'
testRuntimeOnly 'org.junit.vintage:junit-vintage-engine:5.8.1'

...

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()

    testLogging {
        events "STARTED", "SKIPPED", "PASSED", "FAILED"
        showStackTraces true
        showCauses true
        exceptionFormat "full"
    }
}
```

junit-platform.properties:

```
junit.jupiter.testmethod.order.default=org.junit.jupiter.api.MethodOrderer$Random
junit.jupiter.testclass.order.default=org.junit.jupiter.api.ClassOrderer$Random
```

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't. `@ClassOrderer` is an annotation only processed by the Jupiter test engine. You can see that by its package name `org.junit.jupiter.api`.

Features that build on one engine cannot use features of another one, unless the other engine supports that feature explicitly. Since JUnit vintage is mostly there to allow a smooth migration from JUnit 4 to JUnit 5, there will never be support for Jupiter features in JUnit 4 - unless you build it yourself, of course.

Comment: I was afraid of that. As a one-off trick I used debugger to shuffle `org.junit.platform.engine.support.descriptor.AbstractTestDescriptor#children` and it worked. But for a less hacky solution I guess I would need to build a fork of junit-vintage engine.

Comment: Or just migrate the testclass you want to shuffle to Jupiter.